# Combine bar plot and line plot in seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart, seaborn, linechart

I am trying to combine two different plots here, one is a bar plot another is a line plot

I have the below code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 7))

# Plot 1: Line chart for loan distribution over years
plt.subplot(1, 4, 1)
cx = loan_data.groupby('issue_d_year').loan_amnt.count().plot(kind='line', fontsize=7)
for p in cx.patches:
    cx.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.2f'), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha = 'center', va = 'center', xytext = (0, 10), textcoords = 'offset points')
plt.title("Number of Loans over years", weight ='bold')
plt.ylabel("Count of loan amount")
plt.xlabel("Loans funded across years")


# Plot 2: bar chart for loan distribution over years
plt.subplot(1, 4, 2)
cxs = loan_data.groupby('issue_d_year').loan_amnt.count().plot(kind='bar', fontsize=7)
for p in cxs.patches:
    cxs.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.2f'), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha = 'center', va = 'center', xytext = (0, 10), textcoords = 'offset points')
plt.title("Number of Loans over years", weight ='bold')
plt.ylabel("Count of loan amount")
plt.xlabel("Loans funded across years")

plt.figure(figsize=(70, 7))

# Plot 3: Line chart for loan distribution over months
plt.subplot(1, 4, 3)
dx = loan_data.groupby('issue_d_month').loan_amnt.count().plot(kind='line', fontsize=7)
for p in dx.patches:
    dx.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.2f'), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha = 'center', va = 'center', xytext = (0, 10), textcoords = 'offset points')
plt.title("Number of Loans over months", weight ='bold')
plt.ylabel("Count of loan amount")
plt.xlabel("Loans funded across months")


# Plot 4: Bar chart for loan distribution over months
plt.subplot(1, 4, 4)
dxs = loan_data.groupby('issue_d_month').loan_amnt.count().plot(kind='bar', fontsize=7)
for p in dxs.patches:
    dxs.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.2f'), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha = 'center', va = 'center', xytext = (0, 10), textcoords = 'offset points')
plt.title("Number of Loans over months", weight ='bold')
plt.ylabel("Count of loan amount")
plt.xlabel("Loans funded across months")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Is there a way i can combine the top 2 charts into one and the bottom 2 into one and have the line colored in red

Comment: Pandas' bar plot always uses a categorical x-axis. The line plot uses a numeric x-axis. Converting the years to strings would have both plots using a categorical x-axis. For example `loan_data['issue_d_year'] = loan_data['issue_d_year'].astype(str)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem in combining bar plot and line plot (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614007/problem-in-combining-bar-plot-and-line-plot-python)